# Prevent duplicates from being entered onto database

Tags: vb.net

Well I am trying to get the program to not accept records that are already present which is determined by the "PRODNAME" by using SQL codes.

Don't know how and where to place those other sql codes because our prof just kept on giving us program exercises without even explaining...its like a self discovery class T_T

BY THE WAS HERE IS A SNIPPET OF MY CODES:

```
verify = "SELECT * FROM Products"
    recordset.Open(verify, connection, 3, 3)
    If ... Then
        recordset.AddNew()
        recordset.Fields("prodSKU").Value = prodSKU.Text
        recordset.Fields("prodName").Value = prodName.Text
        recordset.Fields("prodSRP").Value = prodSRP.Text
        recordset.Fields("ProdDesc").Value = prodDesc.Text
        recordset.Fields("ProdUnit").Value = comboUnit.Text
        recordset.Update()
        recordset.Close()
        MsgBox("Record added SUCCESS!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "SUCCESS")
        comboUnit.Items.Clear()
        recordset.Open("SELECT DISTINCT Produnit FROM products", connection, 3, 3)
        Do While Not recordset.EOF
            comboUnit.Items.Add(recordset.Fields("Produnit").Value)
            recordset.MoveNext()
        Loop
        recordset.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox("Duplicates found", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "ERROR")
        recordset.Close()
    End If
```

Comment: Why are you using ADODB rather than ADO.Net? Do you need to prevent dupes from being entered into the program itself or just the database? Usually it's just the latter which is taken care of by a unique (or primary) key. The database will return an error which your program then handles appropriately.

Comment: `its like a self discovery class` Programming will on occasion require you to think and be creative. Its not like paint by number.  Are you sure you are using VB.NET?

Comment: yeah we haven't tackled ADO.net yet dunno why... i need to prevent dupes from being entered in the program itself... just wanna cry right now

Comment: Is VB and VB.net the same?

Comment: We are using VB 2010...

Comment: You might like to add a Unique constraint on the column that must be unique.